# Cannot add accent marks on character, as accent marks immidiately appear before the next key press

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

In short, I am trying to type the acute e (`é`) character.

For some reason, on my office computer (Linux Mint Cinnamon), I cannot write the character as I am used to.

The way I would normally do it, is by pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>, release, <kbd>e</kbd>. The problem with this system is that the acute character `´` immediately appears, and the `e` character after it.

So instead of `é`, I get `´e`.

It is the same for other characters, for instance, if I wanted `ñ`, I would press <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>¨</kbd>, then <kbd>n</kbd>. But in reality, I get `~n`. Then `~` immediately appears.

My keyboard layout is Norwegian.